# How to bind more then one column to a textview

Tags: android, sqlite

I am curious if there is a way to bind more then one db column to a resource. I need to bind more information to R.id.secondLine then just the difficulty column. But I'm unsure how to go about this? I'm currently subclassing SimpleCursorAdapter. Should I subclass another adapter? If so How to do I go about it?

```
    Cursor activityHikes = mDbAdapter.fetchAllHikes(false);
    startManagingCursor(activityHikes);

    String[] from = new String[] { ActivityHike.NAME, ActivityHike.DIFFICULTY, ActivityHike.THUMBNAIL};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.mainText, R.id.secondLine, R.id.icon};

    HikeAdapter hikes = new HikeAdapter(this, R.layout.hike_row, activityHikes, from, to);
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.hikelist);
    list.setAdapter(hikes);
```

Thanks

For anyone who has this same problem this link helped me alot too.
[Android: Binding data from a database to a CheckBox in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can bind more than one column to a view using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.  Your best bet would be to subclass `CursorAdapter` and implement `bindView` to do any special formatting you want to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement your own ViewBinder and pass that to your SimpleCursorAdapter.  This gives you full access to the cursor when setting the values of each View.