# ListView With checkbox and images in android

Tags: android, list, view

please someone help me about this.
i need to implement a list view with checkbox and each item should be assosiated with images.
ex:

```
[image1] list_item_1       [checkbox]
[image2]  list_item_2      [checkbox]
                   '
                   .
                   .
```

please help me

Comment: i think you, try to this [Question][1]  




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485870/listview-with-multiple-checkbox-and-image-view

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a [ListAdapater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) as a kind of "template" for the items in the ListView. You might want to take a look at this [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview).

Comment: but i need to loop through all items . i need to check whether item is checked or not and need to do some processing on checked items..

Comment: The checkbox on the UI is just a representation of some variable in your data model. If you need to do some sort of processing, you'd process the underlying data items, not the stuff shown in the UI. That's how modern data-driven applications work.