# How to remove values from listview based on checkbox enabling in android

Tags: android

How to remove values from the list-view based on the checkbox selection in android .

currently i am using public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {} to call the checkbox initializing and calling . can you pls help me to remove values from the listview

Please Help me I am struck here for the past three days .

Comment: you want to remove a list view item that has been checked?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834615/how-to-implement-check-box-in-listview-android-to-delete-listitems

Comment: i will post the code Mr.Denis vasilenko on 10/12/2013 morning

Answer (score 0):

Write a Check box OnClickListener like this

```
chksin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

  int count = this.mainListView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (this.mainListView.isItemChecked(i)) {
            painItems.remove(i)
        }
    }

        }
});
```

Then refresh the adapter :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```