# Problem with adding checkbox inside a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have added a checkbox inside a list view, but i am able to select and unselect only the checkboxes but i cannot select the list item. How to overcome this problem? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

My Code Goes Here

```
List<String> lst = dh.selectAll();
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.textViewx,lst);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

dh.selectall() -> Contains the listarray of items from database;
lv -> list view identified
I've used array adapter and identified a textview to enter items in listview
at last, I've given a clicklistener to the listview by implementing OnItemClickListener.

Comment: You can find more detail and example about [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417339/android-listview-with-checkbox-and-all-clickable

Comment: Including the problematic code in your question will most likely yield better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use multiple choice listview. Fits your needs perfectly. Here is a link to a good tutorial : http://mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-create-multiple-choice-list

### Update 1

```
listViewObj.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

When you have a checkable item in your listview, the touch on item will not be delivered to item. Just to test, set  your checkbox as non clickable. `chkox.setClickable(false);` and test. The clicks will be delivered to your item.

### Update 2

You should use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` for list item.

```
List<String> lst = dh.selectAll();
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lst);

lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
lv.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thats fine. Just use listview object directly instead of calling `getListView`

Comment: Add your current code to the question. Which layout id are you passing to your adapter?

Comment: You should set android:focusable="false" in the XML layout for your checkbox in the list item. Otherwise the checkbox will steal all click events and your list view will not get them.

Answer (score 1):

with out these two lines the list will display
the check box but would not be able to check/unchek

```
ListView listView = getListView();
mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: I can only select and de-select the checkboxes. But i cannot select a list item....