# CheckBox showing unusual behaviour in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Below I have written my code actually when I was scrolling my listview the checkbox takes its original position, any help by code will be appreciated.

```
 cp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cp.setChecked(true);
        cx.setChecked(false);

        ck.setChecked(false);
        int a=1;

        String c=getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        updatetable(c, "FULL");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c+"full", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

 cx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cx.setChecked(true);
        cp.setChecked(false);
        ck.setChecked(false);
        int a=1;
        String c=getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        updatetable(c, "CRITICAL");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c+"ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

 ck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)  {
            ck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ck.setChecked(true);
            cp.setChecked(false);
            cx.setChecked(false);
            int a=1;
    String c=getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    updatetable(c, "FINISH");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c+"fineshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: your question is not clear!!!

Comment: no need to yell there. there are quite a few post related to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417339/android-listview-with-checkbox-and-all-clickable. please check them :)

Comment: your onClick method should have the override annotation. Also, a little refactoring would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think I got the problem.

I think this is not a matter of `CheckBox`. I think you're doing something wrong with your adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Something> mList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Something> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        /* Here you should set your checkbox state */
    }
}
```

I think your problem is `convertView`.

When you scroll down your `ListView` the popped up items are not destroyed, but recycled. The recycled item is given you back as `convertView`. `convertView` **is not cleaned**, hence if the `CheckBox` in the popped out item was checked, the `CheckBox` in `convertView` is checked.

You have to maintain a `List<Boolean> states` where you save the state of the `CheckBox` of all your items. Then:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(states.get(position));
    }
```

I haven't your code, so the example above is as general as possible. If you let us see the code we can help you.