# Checkbox not clickable in simple listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have simple listview (Not custom listview) with checkbox in right side but these checkboxes are not clickable.

Here is my **MainActivity.java** Code:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray)));
```

and here is xml code:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    </ListView>
```

Also I need help to find out which checkbox was clicked on click of some button.

I have seen may questions posted on stackoverflow but they were all realeated to custom listview.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417339/android-listview-with-checkbox-and-all-clickable) SO question, basically you'll need to set the checkbox focusable as false.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and now i am able to click on checkboxes but Can u help me in finding out what all checkboxes were checked(on click of a button). Please modify your above code.