# how to implement a checkbox in each row in a Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

It's my first Andoid app. I can't implement a multiple choise in my ListView(i want a checkbox in every row in my listview).
I'm using the notepadv3 tutorial.
Can someone help me, i'm a newbie in java.

```
private void fillData() {
     ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    //lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<CheckBox android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    />

<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_notes"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the checkbox in the xml layout R.layout.notes_row. If you post your xml code we might be able to help you more.

Comment: i can't implement the checkbox in notes_row xml

Comment: Ertan, if you found my answer helpful. Please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to my response.

Answer (score 0):

This thread in SO shows you how to display a `CheckBox` and `TextView` in each row of `ListView` and how to bind them to the database: 
[Android: Binding data from a database to a CheckBox in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview)

You might want to have a look.