# Getting checkbox information from a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have an activity with a list fragment in it that has a layout with a checkbox for each row. I set the `onclick` xml attribute for the checkbox and do the following for testing

```
public void onBoxClick(View v){
    checkedItems = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();

}
```

`checkedItemsCount` comes back `0`, I thought to get what items that are checked you use the `listview.getCheckedItemPositions()` but it is not so how do I know what is checked in the list?

this is my listfragment creation

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
        super.onActivityCreated(state);
        listview = getListView();
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        setEmptyText("No Bowlers");       
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        populateList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the problem by Custom Adapter's `bindView`, I created an `ArrayList<Integer>` variable

```
ArrayList<Integer> mCheckedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and In the `bindView` I set a `checkedchangelistener` on the checkbox to see if the box was checked or not. If it was checked I put the id from the database that the cursor got into the `mCheckedItems Array`

adapter:

```
public class CheckAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Context context;

    public CheckAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to,int flag) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context,Cursor cursor){
        final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BowlersDB.NAME));
        final int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BowlersDB.ID));
        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameCheckTV);
        tv.setText(name);

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    mCheckedItems.add(id);
                }else if(!isChecked){
                    for(int i=0; i< mCheckedItems.size(); i++){
                        if(mCheckedItems.get(i) == id){
                            mCheckedItems.remove(i);
                        }
                    }                   
                }

            }

        });
    }
```

After the id was inserted into the array I used the array list to used them how I needed

Answer (score 0):

This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview) might help. It gives a solution using a custom `ResourceCursorAdapter`, which provides a `CheckBox` and a `TextView` for each `ListView` row.

To select multiple items in `ListView`, check this [**page**](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/). Note that the example uses a `ListActivity` instead of a `ListFragment`, but your code will end up being extremely similar. Just make sure you implement the `Fragment` lifecycle methods correctly (i.e. setting the Adapter in the `ListFragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`, etc.).