# adding a checkbox to an existing listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i have a list view. it works fine.
what i want is to add a checkbox for every line in the list view.
thats my code:

```
public class List extends ListActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
      while(true){
          if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
              break;
          }
      }
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
  ArrayList<String> arrayOfBluetoothDevicesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
      arrayOfBluetoothDevicesNames.add(bt.getName());
  }
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, arrayOfBluetoothDevicesNames));
  ListView listViewOfBluetooth = getListView();
```

is ther a simple way of doing it by changing my code?

Comment: im new at this...  i tried changing tha xmlfile of the list with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solution for multiple selection in listview..

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview)

[Solution 2](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/)

[Solution 3](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)

Comment: thanks, but i was wondering if there is a way to modify my code and get the same result...

Comment: I think you have to use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter for multiple selection on listview so you have to change yr code