# How to add checkbox to each item in listview

Tags: java, android, checkbox

i am working on a calander app. a listview which shows all calendar available.
how can add a checkbox to it and also
the calendar selected before should show checked.

i want a list view like this.

textview   cb

Comment: what have you tried? At least do some research before asking question here.

Comment: Have a look.. You'll get all your answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

Set the listview adapter to "simple_list_item_multiple_choice"

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

List<String> values; // put values in this

//Put in listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<UserProfile>(
this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
values);
setListAdapter(adapter);   //Set the adpter to list View
```

Second method would be to create a Custom Adapter By extending the Base adapter class:

Look at the example in the link:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: simple_list_item_multiple_choice 
this thing is fine. but how can i work with checked unchecked state???

Comment: please have a look at the following links it would clear all your doubts:

http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-checkboxes-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkedTextView for you ListView rows(using custom adapter) and specify          android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" to your list view

Here is a sample from my code:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_txt" />
```

Here, it will add checked drawable as you tap on CheckedTextView

Now,Store selected items in List<> and you can add and remove on click

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
    if (ctv != null) {
        if (ctv.isChecked()) {
            ctv.setChecked(false);
            listAdapter.removeSelectedMembers(position);
        } else {
            ctv.setChecked(true);
            listAdapter.setSelectedMembers(position);
        }
    }
}
```

//adapter Methods of adding and removing Item

```
public void setSelectedMembers(int position) {
    if (!selectedMembersList.contains(String.valueOf(position))) {
        selectedMembersList.add(String.valueOf(position));
    }
}

public void removeSelectedMembers(int position) {
    selectedMembersList.remove(String.valueOf(position));
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can access checked state using isChecked() method. I am editing my code here