# SimpleCursorAdapter returns an integer key for a string - how to convert to corresponding string?

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

My program uses a database which has table with an integer column,  meant to contain numbers 1 - 4 corresponding to 4 different strings. I have a `SimpleCursorAdapter` which updates a listview of my table's columns via a `LoaderManager()`. I am using a `ContentProvider` to interface with my database.

I have an array with the strings `R.array.stringArray`.

How can I get the listview of my `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display the string instead of the integer? Is there a part of the api (which I have missed) which allows one to do this with `SimpleCursorAdapter`s? Or any other way?

Thank you for your help.

nme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, if you are extending `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you may want to check its `getView`-method and use something like,

```
String idStr = cursor.getString(<column index>);
```

You can use `Cursor`'s `getString`-method to retrieve integer/long values, for example,

- `getInt` will return the value as plainly 3, when using `getString` it will return "3" instead

EDIT:

```
// you say its from 1-4, say it returns 3
int index = cursor.getInt(<the column index>);

// subtracted 1 because arrays start at index 0 instead of 1 on your database
String stringEquivalent = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringArray)[index - 1];
```

Comment: But 3 corresponds to "string number three"; how do I display "string number three", which is not in the database, in my `ListView` rather than "3" if it is going to use a `SimpleCursorAdaptor`

Comment: So "string number three" is on your R.array.stringArray? If that is so, then you could just do that I added above.

Comment: You may also look into a [`ViewBinder`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview/1812571#1812571).